# How to recreate SecureRandom instances and compare them?

Tags: java, security, cryptography

I am creating a secure random number like this:

```
SecureRandom challange = new SecureRandom();
final byte[] number = new byte[32];
challange.nextBytes(number);
```

and then convert it to Base64 like this (not sure if generateSeed messes it up):

```
byte[] secureBytes = challange.generateSeed(32);
byte[] base64secure = Base64.encode(secureBytes);
```

after that i send it through a TCP socket and read it on the other end.

How can I create a new SecureRandom instance out of the bytes received?
And how can I compare two SecureRandom instances if they are the same numbers? (e.g. the number created in the beginning with the new instance created out of the byte array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just looked into this a bit more and there is no way to do it. The point of SecureRandom is that it by cryptographically secure and seeding the values would prevent it:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

      SecureRandom seedMaker = new SecureRandom();  
      byte[] seed = seedMaker.generateSeed(20);
      SecureRandom r1 = new SecureRandom(seed);
      SecureRandom r2 = new SecureRandom(seed);

      byte[] b1 = new byte[4];
      byte[] b2 = new byte[4];
      for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        r1.nextBytes(b1);
        r2.nextBytes(b2);

        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(b1)+" == "+java.util.Arrays.toString(b2));
      }
    }
}
```

Try it here: http://www.tryjava8.com/app/snippets/52c56f1de4b00bdc99e8a99c

You can immediately see that the results do not match.

To get the behaviour you desire you can only do it using the standard `Random` number generator and seed that, you can't do it with `SecureRandom`.

Comment: I suppose this will be provider-dependent behaviour, since the Javadocs do not require that the seed is ignored or that two identical seeds should not produce non-indentical outputs. Also note that your example might be easier to read if you concluded with `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.equals(b1, b2));`.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to visibly see the difference but Arrays.equals is a good choice too.

Comment: You should use a stream cipher instead of a `SecureRandom` with seed. Your code will break between different java versions/implementations. I believe there are even some implementations which ignore the seed or just add it to the entropy pool. I recommend using AES in CTR mode.

Comment: The answer above is correct. For my problem using IvParameterSpec instead of SecureRandom  for the AES IV params did the trick for me, because you can initialize it with a byte array.